# test NSDictionary valueForKey using ISEqualToString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I am using an `IF` statement to see if the valueForKey is @"T" in my `NSDictionary`, however i don't think i am accessing the `NSDictionary` correctly because even when i know the valueForKey is T is never enters the `IF` statement.

This is what my code looks like:

```
if ([[getObj valueForKey:@"hasSetID"] isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
        [arrayOfButtonImages addObject:firstButtonImage];
    }
```

So this if statment is never entered even if it is T.

If any one knows how to test the valueforkey of a `NSDictionary` it would be greatly appreciated if you could help me with your insight.

Comment: `NSArray *keys = [getObj allKeys];` try this and print it, then you will be able to see all keys of **dictionary**. One more thing may be any white space is append with keys so in this case it would not exact equal to `@"T"`.

Comment: do you want to search within the Keys of the Dictionary or get its values?

Comment: [This works for me, just like it is supposed to work.](http://ideone.com/DIU6LM)

Comment: How do you know the value is `@"T"`?

Comment: @H2CO3 - He is doing same ..... I think problem is in how he is making the dictionary.

Comment: [getObj valueForKey:@"hasSetID"] instead try with [getObj objectForKey:@"hasSetID"]

Comment: @VenkatManoharPerepa NO NO NO NO NO, that's what I'm talking about - it's (almost) the same for `NSDictionary`. OP's code **should** work.

Comment: Do you mean objectForKey and valueForKey are same ?? @H2CO3

Comment: @VenkatManoharPerepa It would be enough to read the documentation of `NSDictionary` before giving wrong answers based on lazy assumptions. [Read this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ), it clearly states what the equivalence and the difference is.

Comment: @TheTiger No, `valueForKey:` is not "better", and it doesn't "work with any class". It has a different use case.

Comment: @H2CO3: Hold on!!!! Do you know the difference between objectForKey and valueForKey ??

Comment: @VenkatManoharPerepa I do, and if you click on the link I provided, you will know it too. (Also, stop duplicating your question marks, one of them is enough.)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Can you explain it ?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know because I can NSLog the dictionary and see all the keyValueName = T etc. maybe its not a string? could it be like a bool maybe? or dose every value in a valueforkey of type nsstring?

Comment: @TheTiger `valueForKey:` is for accessing KVC-compliant properties. `objectForKey:` is the only method that is usable on `NSDictionary` when the key starts with `@`. Neither one is better than the other, they are to be used in different situations.

Comment: @HurkNburkS store `[getObj valueForKey:@"hasSetID"]` in `id` and then you can check its class by using `isKindOfClass:` method.

Comment: @TheTiger i wnat to check the string in the valueForKey what do you mean by isKindOfClass

Comment: @HurkNburkS - Do you know how to use debugger ?

Comment: @TheTiger yes, I know how to use it. It shows my NSDictionary and I can look at its keyvalues too.

Comment: for(id key in [getObj allKeys]){
    id value = [getObj valueForKeykey];
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSString Class]])
      NSLog(@"this is a string");
}

Comment: do it in this way ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to work, and [it does indeed](http://ideone.com/DIU6LM). The error is somewhere else. Try logging the contents of your dictionary:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

to see if the key really is `@"hasSetID"`, and the value is indeed `@"T"`. Don't you have an extra whitespace character in one of them? etc.

Comment: i didnt downvote...

when i log the NSDictionary I get this

{
HasASPID = F;
    firstInfoSetID = F;
    secondInfoSetID = F;
    thirdInfoSetID = T;
//etc
}

Comment: @HurkNburkS Neither of the keys is `hasSetID` in that.

Comment: Yes both're wrong ..... :)

Comment: I didnt downvote too. I wont even do that.

Comment: I didn't downvote too.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry there is a key called hasset its further down its defiantly there i have tested for it by logging it etc. I jsut didnt want to add every valueforkey because there are a few of them.. thats why i added the //etc

Comment: @HurkNburkS Could you please log that key and the corresponding value character-by-character, after having checked that both of them `isKindOfClass:[NSString class]`?

Comment: I think actually they might be of type booL! I just checked where I am making the NSDictionay.. damnit what an idiot.. how do i test for T or F if I am saving that into a BOOl

Comment: @HurkNburkS If a `BOOL` is stored in an `NSDictionary`, it's generally done by wrapping it in an `NSNumber`. In that case, its descirption is either `0` or `1`, so here you can be sure it's not an `NSNumber` containing a `BOOL`. Log its class using `NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"hasSetID"] class]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one:

```
if([[yourDictionary allValues]containsObject:@"T"]){
    // Your code here if T is existing
}
else{
    // your code here if its "T" is not existing
}
```